# Custom CSS overwritten by bootstrap.css.map?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and I'm trying to set padding for nav links inside navbar in my custom CSS file:

```
.nav-link {
padding: 0.15rem;
```

}

And the style that is used is this:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the custom.css is nowhere to be seen. The css file where the current style is from is inside bootstrap.css.map.

Why is it reading the style from bootstrap.css.map and not from my custom CSS file? I bundled all styles together, the bootstrap.css is loaded first and my custom CSS is loaded last.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how specificity is calculated in css, it is an easy topic.

If you want a quick solution, you can use !important next to your css styling like so :

```
td { height: 50px !important; }
```

Comment: Inline styles have the highest specificity when added to an element they always overwrite any styles in external stylesheets. can you try that for now and tell me if it works ?

Comment: Yes, inline styling works but it using the aforementioned style inline also changes the padding of some submenu links which is not what I want: http://prntscr.com/krl0i3

Comment: First check if your custom css file is imported and works properly on the page, then give your element another class name and write your styling with the new class name. (I highly recommend you to read about specificity in css)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my original answer I looked at the debugger output.

If you need an overwrite. In one of my projects I gave the surrounding  tag an id.

```
<ul id="myNavBar">
```

Then the following CSS worked for me

```
#myNavBar .link-item {
  padding: 0.15rem;
}
```